# Error "NoneType" procesamiento de imagenes

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Cuando ejecuto este código, me aparece error; cual es el error?:

```
import cv2

imagen_1 = cv2.imread("estrella.jpg")

#Convertir la imagen en escala gris
imagen_gris = cv2.cvtColor(imagen_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imagen_gris, 127,255,0)

#Determina los contornos
contorno, jerarquia = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
cnt = contorno[0]

#Determinar los defectos de convexidad
envoltura = cv2.convexHull(cnt, returnPoints = False)
defectos = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, envoltura)

#Dibujar la envoltura convexa y los defectos de convexidad
for k in range(defectos.shape[0]):
    i,f,l,d = defectos[k,0]
    inicio= tuple(cnt[i][0])
    fin= tuple(cnt[f][0])
    lejos = tuple(cnt[l][0])
    cv2.line(imagen_1,inicio,fin,[0,255,255],2)
    cv2.circle(imagen_1,lejos,5,[0,0,255],-1)

cv2.imshow("Imagen", imagen_1)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#Guardar imagen

cv2.imwrite("Imagen_convexa.jpg",imagen_1)
```

Error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> 14
> 15 #Dibujar la envoltura convexa y los defectos de convexidad
> ---> 16 for k in range(defectos.shape[0]):
> 17     i,f,l,d = defectos[k,0]
> 18     inicio= tuple(cnt[i][0])
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Cual es el error??

Comment: Pues que la variable `defectos` no trae nada. ¿Por qué no imprimes el type justo después de la declaración? Yo creo que el problema debe estar en el retorno de la función `cv2.convexityDefects()`

Comment: Si dejo vacía la función `cv2.convexityDefects()` me pide el que ponga la variable contorno dentro de los paréntesis.